# IPA server NFS services adding issue centos 7.2

Tags: linux, redhat, nfs, kerberos, freeipa

I'm having an issue with adding NFS services to IPA server (after login to the IPA server and kinit admin). When I execute the line below:

```
[root@ipa ~]# ipa service-add nfs/server1.example.com
```

I'm getting the error

```
ipa: ERROR: Host does not have corresponding DNS A/AAAA record
```

I have configured the 3 servers correctly and installed FreeIPA in IPA server
Centos 7.2.

My IPA server config

```
IP4.ADDRESS 192.168.1.105/24
IP4.GATEWAY:192.168.1.1
ipv4.dns:8.8.8.8

[root@ipa ~]# vim /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search example.com
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

also config server1 correctly

```
[root@ipa ~]# ipa host-show
Host name: server1
Host name: server1.example.com
Principal name: host/server1.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
Password: False
Keytab: False
Managed by: server1.example.com
```

Comment: you needed to use command `ipa dnsrecord-add` to add a DNS record of type A.since your global dns config should be empty. you can check it with `ipa dnsconfig-show`

Answer (score 1):

Hosts need to have their IPv6 and IPv4 addresses registered in the domain's DNS before you can do much of anything with them.

When you join the NFS server to the domain, ensure that you enable automatic DNS updates. This is not currently the default behavior (though it really should be). For example:

```
ipa-client-install --enable-dns-updates
```

If you've already joined the server to the domain, then you'll need to reconfigure it to update DNS. Edit `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` and enable dynamic DNS updates. You may also need to specify the NIC for which DNS updates will be sent. For example:

```
[domain/example.com]
dyndns_update = True
dyndns_iface = enp2s1
```

Once reconfigured, restart sssd with `systemctl restart sssd` or restart the computer.

You could also manually insert DNS records, but this very quickly becomes one of the maintenance nightmares that having an IPA domain solves.